# Is Powershell built on RESTFUL architecture?

Tags: rest, powershell

I am learning Powershell recently, and looking all these standardized Verbs and usage of Nouns next to them to handle a resource brought up the question that

Could we say Powershell is built on top of the RESTFUL architecture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an intensive period of research (5 minutes) I can see how some parallels might be drawn between RESTful architecture and how PowerShell appears to a user. Referring to the REST concepts listed on Wikipedia...

- Vocabulary re-use vs arbitrary extension. PowerShell makes repeated use of Get, Set, New & Remove in a similar way to RESTs re-use of GET, POST, PUT & DELETE.
- REST has a core concept of Resources which might be seen as analogous to PowerShell's providers. Resources are accessed by URI. Providers enable access to resources by a similar, hierarchical method.
- Finally, participants in a RESTful architecture exchange documents representing the state of resource collections and items. PowerShell CmdLets exchange objects which represent the underlying Provider resources.

So, I can kind of see some similarities, but this is probably a long way from saying that PowerShell is "built on top of a RESTful architecture".

Comment: So if we remove hyperlink from the definition of Restful architecture, and random extension of the verbs from Powershell , we get close ?

Comment: Hi Sureyya, I wrote my answer because I felt that, Ravikanth's response was based on a very literal interpretation of the question and possibly mis-apprehension that REST = Web Services. I'm not an expert in the semantics of PowerShell or REST though, so cannot give you a definitive answer. Is there a problem that you are need to solve, or a point you are trying to prove?

Comment: Hey andy, I am also not very clear about REST concept, so I am trying to map as much possible things as i can to prove the concept to myself. But I guess you and ravikanth made the point clear , that RESTFUL architecture should depend on HTTP endpoints and certain verb standards which should not be extendible otherwise it will be against the one of the corner stone of REST which says the RESTFUL architecture should be self-explanatory. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

No. PowerShell is not based on any web services. It uses .NET as the foundation. The PowerShell web services in Server 2012 etc is about how you can execute PowerShell commands over HTTP/HTTPS endpoints. But, that said, PowerShell is not based on the RESTFul architecture. It is an object-based, distributed automation engine built on top of .NET.

Comment: Hi Ravikanth thanks for the answer , but Web is not based on any web services but it is a restful architecture. I believe my question is a bit misleading , maybe I can ask like this, do you think Powershells basic idea of architecture has some parallels to the rest architecture.